# how do I check if firstname does not exists in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

How do I check if the firstname is not filled and I've tried not null like this:

```
DELIMITER go

    Create procedure registerusers(
      Out UserID tinyint(11),
     IN iFirstName varchar(30),
     IN iLastName varchar(30),
     IN iPassword varchar(30),
     IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
     IN iSalt varchar(40),
     IN iRoleID varchar(1))
    BEGIN

      /* I've used not null and it works for empty firstname but when I
        try to pass the firstname it didn't work and I kept getting an error message saying "fill out the firstname" */
    If(iFirstName not null) then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';

    else

    insert into users(
        /* insert into user if its not empty */
    FirstName,
     LastName ,
     Password ,
     EmailAddress ,
     Salt ,
     RoleID 
     )
    Values
    (
    iFirstName,
     iLastName ,
     iPassword ,
     iEmailAddress ,
     iSalt ,
     iRoleID 
    );
    set UserID = last_insert_id();  
     end if;

    End
    go
    DELIMITER ;
```

However when I used

```
set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'','Jones','5566','jones@gmail.com','sdfd','1');
select @new_id;
```

it manages to display an error message but when I used

```
set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'Jason','Jones','5566','jones@gmail.com','sdfd','1');
select @new_id;
```

for inserting the firstname it kept displaying an error message other than wanting to insert the data.

I've tried `if(firstname is null)` but it didn't work because it went pass through message. For example if I used

```
set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'','Jones','5566','jones@gmail.com','sdfd','1');
select @new_id;
```

as empty for firstname it went through and it suppose to display an error message. If I used

```
set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'Jason','Jones','5566','jones@gmail.com','sdfd','1');
select @new_id;
```

it manages to go through.

Comment: The syntax should be `if (firstname IS NOT NULL)`. You're missing the word `IS`.

Comment: An empty string is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `tinyint` for the auto-increment ID in the table. That will only allow 255 rows in the table.

Comment: I've tried if(firstname is null) but it actually insert the data without firstname

Comment: These column limits are absurdly small. 30 characters for an email address? `TINYINT` for a user ID? Use `INT` and `VARCHAR(255)` unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

Comment: But you should probably use `IF (iFirstName = '')` to test if an empty name was given.

Comment: Additionally, doing insertion validation in the database instead of in the application layer is something straight out of the 1980s. This is really going to be trouble to maintain.

Comment: Like I said before: an empty string is not the ssame as `NULL`.